# centering contact form content

Tags: html, css, position

I have built a relatively simple contact form, cant seem to center the actual content (it currently sits on the left,i'm hoping to move it dead center), my logic is the margin auto class  should have worked but no luck, thanks in advance to anyone who can see where my logic is wrong.

forms are a bit new to me,maybe i'm supposed to be targeting a different element?

```
<section id="contact">
      <div class="contact-title">
        <h2>Lets talk about building your new site</h2>
        <h3>Contact me today and ill be in touch soon</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-form">
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">



          <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
          <br>

          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required>
          <br>


           <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
          <br>

          <textarea name="message" class="form-control"  cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Message goes here"></textarea>
          <br>

          <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">

        </form>
      </div>
   </section>
```

CSS

```
#contact {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,50,0.5),rgba(0,0,50,0.5)),url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491986926302-149ec463b90a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f34dc245ab45d60718efaa50bcdecee1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

.contact-title {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top:50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-title h2 {
 font-size: 4rem;

}


form {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
  width:600px;
  background:transparent; 
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  color:#fff;
}


.form-control:hover {
  width:600px;
  background:transparent; 
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  color:#fff;
}

input {
  height:45px;
}

form .submit {
  background: #ff5722;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

form .submit:hover {
  background: #ff5722;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: What is sitting on the left? I run your code and saw that the form is dead center on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you had fixed width for form controls for 600px and contact form width was 100%. It fills the screen and you can't actually see whether it is centred. In the below snippet I reduced the form control size into 200px and div width to 50% and you can see the form is centered.

```css
#contact {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,50,0.5),rgba(0,0,50,0.5)),url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491986926302-149ec463b90a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=f34dc245ab45d60718efaa50bcdecee1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

.contact-title {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top:50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-title h2 {
 font-size: 4rem;

}


form {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-control {
  width:200px;
  background:transparent; 
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  color:#fff;
}


.form-control:hover {
  width:200px;
  background:transparent; 
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  color:#fff;
}

input {
  height:45px;
}

form .submit {
  background: #ff5722;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

form .submit:hover {
  background: #ff5722;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <div class="contact-form">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
      <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <br>
      <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required>
      <br>
       <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
      <br>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control"  cols="60" rows="10" placeholder="Message goes here"></textarea>
      <br>

      <input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks,it looks perfectly fine in your code snippet when i ran it..but when i used this is my real site it still dosent center it,very frustraing

Comment: Maybe there is another style somewhere in your code that override this style?

Comment: Thanks Kavindra,, are you able to replicate this if you copy the HTML/CSS it to a normal text editor and open in chrome?

Comment: Yes, with proper `<html>`,`<body>` etc tags, it works.@Ravi21